# Career opportunities switching from academia to industry

Tags: phd, academic-life, physics, industry, neuroscience

I'm a physics Undergrad with a huge interest in computation and want to switch to industry. But I also don't want to lose the aspect of the research component of academia. I'm widely interested in biophysics and psychology. I recently found out about the field of cognitive robotics.

Are there other fields I can look into?
And what should I be doing next to get a job in industry ultimately?